# Update select statement result in a column conditioned by another column (Oracle SQL)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a **Select** query in Oracle SQL that will return **first_name** column as empty if last_name column is empty(Regarless what's in the first_name column value).
For the first row "John" should be return as empty since he has no last_name
I don't want to update the table, I just want a Select query that return empty first_name if last_name is empty. Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

[image] THIS SHOULD BE THE OUTCOME.

Comment: use DECODE or CASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       CASE
       WHEN last_name IS NULL
       THEN NULL
       ELSE first_name
       END AS first_name.
       last_name.
       age,
       country
FROM   table_name
```